# Convolution of two-sided exponential function with itself

Tags: exponential-function, convolution

I need to find IFT of :
    H(ω)= $1/(ω^2+a^2)^2$

This H(ω) = $(2a/(ω^2+a^2)) . (2a/(ω^2+a^2)) . (1/4a^2)$

IFT of $(2a/(ω^2+a^2))$ is a two-sided exponential function.... so to find IFT of H(ω), I need to find convolution of two-sided exponential function?

This is how I should go about? If yes, how to find the convolution of of two-sided exponential function with itself??

Comment: Have you tried this at all? It is fairly straightforward. To compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a|y|} e^{-b|x-y|}dy$ first consider the case $x>0$. Split the integral into integrals over $(0,x)$,$(x,\infty)$ etc. each of the integrals it easily computed.

Comment: I am not able to solve for interval y=x to y=infinity ... , I get infinity for that....    for y=0 to y=x I get x*e^-ax ..... for y=x to y= infinity, y gets cancelled, thus just e^-ax remains.... inside integral... the integral is y*e^-ax , so I finally get infinite.... I am not finding it straightforward..

Comment: Also, I am not understanding how you got the b in e^b|x−y| ...For my IFT problem above it cannot be anything other than "a" I thought...

Comment: Yes, $b=a$ in your problem. $\int_x ^{\infty} e^{-ay} e^{-a(y-x)} dx=e^{ax} \int_x ^{\infty} e^{-2ay} dy =e^{ax} e^{2ax}/(2a)$. I don't know how you got $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering patiently....I got it...  Its about handling the mod correctly at positive and negative side.... thankyou